# Adding an array value by key (list)

Tags: php, arrays

I think I’ve recycled and the brains are no longer boiling.
Please tell me how to remove these unnecessary keys inside the keys?

And it seems my foreach is a little crooked, I will be glad to see a hint for solving this problem. Thank you in advance.

What i have on output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => asdasd
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [server] => asdadsasd
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [login] => asdasdads
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => adsads
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [date] => dasadsads
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12123123
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [server] => 123213213
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [login] => 321231123
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 213231213
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 321213213
                )

        )

)
```

What i need to do:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => asdasd
            [server] => asdadsasd
            [login] => asdasdads
            [ip] => adsads
            [date] => dasadsads
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12123123
            [server] => 123213213
            [login] => 321231123
            [ip] => 213231213
            [date] => 321213213
        )

)
```

test2.php code:

```
<?php
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $commands = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        foreach($_POST[$key] as $name => $val) {
            $commands[$name][] = array($key => $val);
        }
    }

    print_r($commands);
    //echo json_encode($commands, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

I try `$commands[$name] = array($key => $val);`, but he stupidly replaced the meaning and substituted a new one, of course.

Php page with form:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="POST" id="insert-all-form">
    <input type="hidden" id="insert-all" name="insert-all">
    <div id="insert-line" class="field is-horizontal m-t-20 dis-block">
        <div class="field-body">
            <?php
                while($prop = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>                    
            <div class="field is-narrow">
                <label class="label"><?=$prop[0]?></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="<?=$prop[0]?>[]" placeholder="<?=$prop[1]?> <?=$prop[5]?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show your html form markup. It will be fixed there.

Comment: Normal `name` attribute should be somehting like `name=data[1][id]`, `name=data[1][server]`, `name=data[1][login]` etc. So you control the index, not just `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u @u_mulder for prompt.
This works for me ->

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $commands = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        foreach($_POST[$key] as $name => $val) {
            $commands[$name][$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    print_r($commands);
?>
```